# How to alert() an img's URL?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to do a popup via JavaScript to popup the IMG URL which is what the img tag is defining through `src=`

I'm not sure how to call it.

```
alert(document.getElementById("my_image").src);
```

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_8049962_source-image-element-using-javascript.html

Comment: what's your problem? Is not your code working now?

Comment: Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/7fY7R/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the `getAttribute()` function:

```
var imageSource = document.getElementById("my_image").getAttribute('src');
alert(imageSource);
```

Using `getAttribute()` is more suitable for your application than simply using `element.src`, since it will return the explicit defined value inside the attribute, rather than the parsed value.

See the comparison here > http://jsfiddle.net/9dAjL/

Comment: Hm, but **why** is it *more reliable*? I guess there is nothing more reliable than value parsed by browser.

Comment: That entirely depends upon the scenario and potential use of the application. I inferred from the question (perhaps erroneously) that he wanted the actual value of the attribute, not the parsed value (i.e. "what the img tag is defining through src=")!

Comment: I have revised the answer.

Comment: Indeed the scenario is very important here, since using `getAttribute` method instead of getting `src` property makes sense only if the URL is set relatively.

Comment: Too bad IE 6-7 [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536429(v=vs.85).aspx) `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

this code is fine

```
 alert(document.getElementById("my_image").src);
```

I would write it more like this

```
 var imageSrc = document.getElementById("my_image").src;
 alert(imgSrc);
```

but reguardless, its fine , I would guess that you are not attaching it to a click event properly or any event for that matter , here is the onload event

```
  window.onload = function() {
     var imageSrc = document.getElementById("my_image").src;
     alert(imgSrc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. Try these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("my_image").src);
    alert(document.getElementById("my_image").getAttribute('src'));
}
</script>

<img src="http://localhost/test.jpg" id="my_image" />
```

Tell more specifically what do you need.

Or you can use names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{

    alert(document["ima"].src);
}
</script>

<img src="http://localhost/ima.jpg" name="ima" />
```